# Semantic web app for my project?

Tags: content-management-system, semantics, multimedia, ontology, owl

I am currently working on a project, let me explain the global idea :

- We have multimedia content (audio, video and PDF files) that we want to share with the worldwide with a CMS.
- Some of the resources are related (same author, same content, next part...) to others.
- We would like to enable an easy navigation between those contents (e.g. a user interface allowing navigation by author, by related content, etc).
- The Internet users could help to categorise / tag the content.
- It could be interesting to propose related content from the Internet.
- This project is a part of another one, a Knowledge Management System for the organisation which make research and produce those contents. A knowledge base would be created for this project, gathering the knowledge existing in the organisation.

I have no Semantic Web background, but hera are my ideas :

- Create an ontology for structuring / linking the multimedia contents together.
- Mount a SPARQL endpoint.
- Execute SPARQL request from the CMS to display navigation links between content and allow user to add new tags.
- Use this kind of architecture for the application: http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-524/swese2009_2.pdf (part 2.4)

I would like to get some advises, especially on those points:

- Is an ontology and a semantic Web application a good solution for my project ?
- Do you have any suggestions about the architecture ?
- What kind of documentation should I consult right now ?

Please feel free to give your global opinion.

Thank you !

Benoît

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic Web technology improves nearly any web application, regardless of domain. Making you content and data more accessible is useful for your organisation and other organisations. Its one of those things that is a win win scenario.

In your case, you want to produce a content management system that incorporates 3 SemWeb use cases:

1. Publishes linked data
2. Consumes linked data
3. Faciliates the linking of data from your datasets with other external datasets.

With regards to publishing linked data, you have a number of options:

1. Publish content using RDFa within existing content
2. Publish content to a public RDF repository or to your own hosted SPARQL endpoint

For the former, there is a great plugin for TinyMCE that facilitates this:

http://aksw.org/Projects/RDFaCE#h13489-4

This also satisfies your 'consuming and linking' use cases (it lets your specify external datasources such as DBPedia and link to things in your RDFa)

As I also understand, Drupal has very good support for RDF:

http://drupal.org/node/222788

Covering most of the use cases above.

You might also want to consider publishing to a SPARQL endpoint offered as a service (SaaS). A good candidate for this is Kasabi (http://kasabi.com) offering a range of data API's including SPARQL.

To do this you will need to have a means by which you can transform your content model / domain model, into RDF. Most CMS system provide a way to enable the creation of new content types, be it through a GUI or a some other convention (some are really just classes). My advice is to build functionality to enrich this process with a means of mapping properties or fields defined as part of a content type, to terms in common vocabularies e.g if someone creates a new content type called 'event' and they specify that an event has a date associated with it, then there should be an extra step to define a term in an ontology the maps to the property in the content type.

This again is something that Drupal with appropriate plugins can do out of the box.

Comment: Thats a great idea. Getting people to markup their web pages using you vocabularies and reconsuming it is one of the major use cases of Sem Web. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like [Webnodes CMS](http://www.webnodes.com/) is a perfect match for you since it sounds like you have limited knowledge of Semantic Web technology and Webnodes has good support for multimedia as well as being a web application framework that you can customize and integrate with your Knowledge Management system.

The CMS lets you create an ontology without having to know anything about RDF/RDFS/OWL. You can create multifaceted structures and metadata taxonomies. Users will be able to tag and create relations between objects and users will be able to navigate between and search/filter items.

They are also working on SPARQL endpoints so you are likely to have that for free in the near future.

Comment: I have taken a look and Webnodes sounds great ! I like the way you can build an ontology easily and the auto set up of the user interface for browsing through related contents.

However do you know free / open source alternatives ? The Webnodes free version limits the number of content URL...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **Semantic Web** paradigm is useful as long as new data structures are involved. **RDF** let us build links between data as nodes in a network. This is a great tool for example when your project needs to work with social media data (who is the friend of a friend (foaf)) or similar.

Another advantage of **SemWeb technologies** is their capability of "reasoning" and discarding bad data due to some kind of logical violation. This is done through **OWL** data that lets you to define certain logical rules.

Nevertheless I think your project could perfectly be developed without any semantic web technology. Just think about two questions to find out if semweb is a requirement to your project:

1.- Are relational structures not enough for your data?

2.- Is your data enough complex to require logical rules to be fulfilled to preserve coherence?

If both questions gives you a negative answer, then avoid semweb implementation. Otherwise, think seriously semweb could help you.

Maybe your project could benefit from another technology somehow related to semweb, but not the same thing canonically speaking. It is **Natural Language**. Through **NL technology** you could establish new interesting relations between data in your **knowledge management system**. For example, a document speaking about profits could be found when searching for "revenues" or "incomes".

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest [Freebase](http://freebase.com)?
It's good for categorizing and tagging the content but also to show related content, as you demanded..
I just wrote an [article on my blog](http://tesladocet.com/programming/freebase-semantic-web-app-google-semantic-search/) about Freebase and how to use it on your own web app. If I have time I'll also publish something on how to set up your machine for semantic web (graph store, sparql etc...)

'a bit late' but hope to be useful

luca